# Formatting Issues With Django & Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have just installed Bootstrap onto my Django site. I have followed the instructions of a couple tutorials.

However, when I view the page via the Django server it is just text based without any formatting. 
Viewing the same page offline (just openning in a web broswer) and the page has all of the Bootstrap formatting.

So, viewing online the formatting doesn't seem to work.
I have followed the tutorial here: 'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/'

However still no luck.

My Template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
```

My Settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Dummy/Documents/Django/ParkManager/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/'
```

....

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'Parks',
        'django_admin_bootstrapped',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

My view

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def Search_Page(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'Details_Main.html', {'request':'index'})
```

Comment: STATIC_URL must be a URL in the form of "http://..." or "/static/whatever". What is the resulting html source of your page in your browser?

Comment: Ah, that does make sense. I'm assuming something on the lines of:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ParkManager/ParkManager/static/?

In my web-browser it hasn't affixed the URL: <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: usually STATIC_URL is just something like '/static'. But STATIC_URL is not being used by your template, as you can see in the href of your <link> tag. Maybe your template is missing the request context. How do you call the template in your view? Can you post your view please?

Comment: Ah okay, thanks
Just added the view relating to this page

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your view does not know anything about the real request context.

please use something similar to

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
...
return TemplateResponse(request, "Details_Main.html", {
    "object": some_object,   # only if you have something to add into the context. otherwise leave the dictionary empty.
})
```

Comment: Ah Okay, 
No where in the documentation or guides I read did anywhere say anything about modifying your view. :S

Anyways, we are getting a lot closer. The URL now reads: <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

Also updated main post to show my changes...